# Unable to start the application using static library

Tags: c++, static-linking, linker-errors

I am using a static library and creating another static library. Then I am using my test application to test my library.

I am able to successfully build both the library(statically build) and the test application.  But, when I am trying to run the application I am getting error,

```
Unable to start program 'C:\Users\LT-BPant\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Test_Lib\Debug\Lib_1.lib'.
```

TO explain,

SDK_C(in C) static library ----->  SDK_CPP(in C++,  this is written by me and it is using SDK_C) -----> Test_SDK (using SDK_CPP). I am getting errors in this Test_SDK application..

I have set the correct path of the SDK_CPP in the Test_SDK project settings. **DO I need to give all the path of SDK_C lib as well and all other dlls that are being used by SDK_C in Test_SDK?** 
As per my knowledge, I should only give the path of the dependent dlls but not static library, since it is statically bound to the project and is needed at compile time.

Comment: Is SDK_CPP a DLL or a static library ? Does Test_SDK make direct calls to SDK_C, and if yes is this API declared extern "C" ?

Comment: Since the error apparently only involves your main program and your C++ library you should be able to reproduce with a similar reduced example, no C library complicating things.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, SDK_CPP is static library. Test_SDK only calls SDK_CPP functions

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I have started with the same thing and it worked for me previously!!

Comment: The missing reference does not seem to have any connection with the C library.

Comment: I have gone through the other reference link but that did not helped me at all... I am statically linking the library...